# Getting 'Illegal characters in path' error while copying files from ADLS Gen2 to local using Az Powershell

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-data-lake-gen2

We have hundreds of thousands of files in ADLS Gen2. I use Azure Storage Explore to browse files. When I need a file from a particular day I have to go through pages of file listings, one by one, manually to get to a certain file .

I wrote this script a few months ago to download all the file based on a certain prefix pattern. It was working just fine but now it seems like there is some problem with it or may be a bug somewhere else.

```
$ListBlobs = Get-AzStorageBlob -Container $azContainerName -Context $connectionContext -Prefix "/staging/test" 

foreach($blob in $ListBlobs) 
{

$blob.Name 

Get-AzDataLakeGen2ItemContent -Context $connectionContext -FileSystem $azContainerName -Path $blob.Name -Destination "C:\test"
}
```

Getting error below:

```
staging/test.csv

Get-AzDataLakeGen2ItemContent : Illegal characters in path.
At C:\Users\Shahsa\documents\powershell\download.ps1:21 char:1
 Get-AzDataLakeGen2ItemContent -Context $connectionContext -FileSystem 
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Get-AzDataLakeGen2ItemContent], ArgumentException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ArgumentException,Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Commands.Storage.Blob.Cmdlet.GetAzDataLakeGen2ItemContentCommand
```

I tried doing a single file copy like below as well with hard coded path:

```
Get-AzDataLakeGen2ItemContent -Context $connectionContext -FileSystem "datalake" -Path "staging/test.csv" -Destination "C:\test1\"
```

This fails with the same error saying illegal characters in paths.

Answer (score 0):

I have tested your code(including hard coded), both of them can work fine on my side.

[image]

According to the error message, maybe there is something wrong with your path. Please check it. If you make sure your path is correct, maybe there is a bug somewhere else as you said.